# Is there a more reliable way to catch line breaks and wrap up the text?

Tags: jquery, line-breaks

I have a userscript I wrote to be able to automatically insert shipping details pasted into a text box (injected into the page by the userscript) into the appropriate fields. The data is generated by another script that reads new entries into a spreadsheet, and the format it comes in is as follows:

```
Name :: Simon

Email :: simon@example.com

Address 1 :: Castle 1

...
```

However, sometimes some of the data is broken down into a second line (usually only happens with the email address, for some reason), which means it'll look like this:

```
...

Email :: 
simon@example.com

...
```

And so, I made it so the usercript catches these too and the function that reads the pasted data looks like this:

```
$('#paste-box').on('paste', function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        var rawData = $('#paste-box').val();
        var data = {};
        rawData = rawData.replace(' :: \n', ' :: ');  //this is the line that catches lines spilling into second line
        rawData = rawData.split('\n');
        for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
            line = rawData[i].split(' :: ');
            if (line.length == 2) data[line[0]] = line[1];
        }
```

This code seems to work just fine — I haven't stumbled on it not catching the line breaks yet. But I was wondering: is there a more elegant and/or reliable way of catching these?

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the text-to-object transformation to its own function to start with if that's possible. Then, if you like, you can bundle the replacing and splitting and length checking into one small string of arcane characters. Or, in other words, use a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
function parseRawData(rawData) {
    var data = {};
    var re = /^(.*) :: \n?(.*)$\n*/gm;
    var match;
    while ((match = re.exec(rawData)) !== null) {
        data[match[1]] = match[2];
    }
    return data;
}
```

That gives you some leeway to find and fix more oddness. Can assert that the whole paste string is consumed, print remaining text in case of mismatches, and adapt your expression to cope.

Comment: To make sure I get this, the Regular Expression is looking for: beginning of input, followed by any string of characters that is not a newline, followed by `::` padded with a space on both sides, followed by _sometimes_ a new line, followed by any string of characters that is not a new line (again), and then followed by the end of input with a newline? That aside, how does `data[match[1]] = match[2]` work here? The idea is that `data` is a collection of key-value objects — in the form of `'Name': 'Simon'`, for instance — will that still do that?

Comment: The capturing parentheses put those sections into the `match` array from index 1 onwards (0 is the whole thing). Note, `re.exec()` is an all or nothing thing, it will return `null`, never put something in part of the array then fail. Finally, the `re` object has a `lastIndex` property, so each time through the loop it's starting from where it left off, so will go through all your pairs.